# Is there a way to quantify your skill levels in sql for entry level positions

Tags: sql

A beginner in SQL here and an aspiring data analyst.
I wanted to see where I am in my journey in SQL. I have been learning from 15-20 days
Now, I know that learning SQL is a life-long journey but, I want to know if my SQL skills are adequate for entry level data analyst jobs.
I have been practicing in sqlzoo.net, I have written these queries with relative ease (if we put it on an ordinal scale of difficulty I would say 4/10 (10 being very difficult))

https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations

1. number 13 :

   ```
   WITH cte as (select count(id) as numberoffilms, actorid as cteid
   FROM movie 
   join casting on movieid = id 
   GROUP BY actorid, ord
   HAVING count(id) >= 15
   AND ord = 1)

   SELECT  name
   From cte 
   join actor on cteid = id 
   ORDER BY name
   ```

```
2)number 15
```

```
SELECT distinct name 
FROM casting 
JOIN actor on actorid=id
WHERE movieid IN (

SELECT movieid  
FROM casting 
where actorid = (select id from actor where name = 'Art Garfunkel'))
AND name <>  'Art Garfunkel'
```

**My questions**

1)Are these queries supposed to be difficult?, 2)what kind of queries do we encounter while on the job. 3)how do I measure my skills? 4) after I solve all the questions on sqlzoo.net, where should I practice next
PS - I don't know if I am supposed to ask these kinds of questions on this site, let me know if this is inappropriate and I will remove it. also, I know this question can come of as super dumb but I took a risk LOL

Comment: I think you are off to a good start, keep going.  Hard to say what a job will require just by title. This likely will get closed as off-topic. Requests for off-site resources like sql tutorials are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Never quantify your skills.

This is a bad practice for any person in IT that wants to apply to a job position.

Lets say you want to apply to this data analyst position who seems to not ask for too much crazy stuff but you put you have 40% SQL skills on your resume (based on your own 4/10 quantification).

Then, wheres the other 50%? What's the metric? What is 100% SQL skill? Does this means you're barely almost half good at SQL?

You should just add the skills you have. Whatever it has to do with what you want to do. Label it on your CV and forget about quantifying it. Don't use progress bars or %s or any other measure for the "amount of skill" that you have.

> Are these queries supposed to be difficult?

> what kind of queries do we encounter while on the job

> how do I measure my skills?

> after I solve all the questions on sqlzoo.net, where should I practice next

These are opinion based questions that will only blind you to the reality of how broad coding can be. Focus on doing projects and practise what you don't know quite yet. Do projects, maybe build an `API` or whatever other thing that adds value to your career. Don't just learn what you wanna do.

You will eventually get a an interview and get a job that will match your expectations. Keep going as you are

Comment: If learning SQL (or any skill) is an unending journey, then by definition, how close you are to finishing that journey is always 0%. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just to be clear, I did not rate my skills with 4/10. I just said that performing these queries was relatively easy as to put my skills in perspective. Anyways, I get the point you're trying to make. I will try to find some projects!

Comment: @BillKarwin I totally agree but I just wanted a scale you know!